# How do I initialize state when I'm extending a component?

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, constructor, setstate

I have a component called `ErrorComponent` whose state is initialized in its constructor.

However, I now want to make a new class called `BaseForm` that extends from `ErrorComponent`.

But if I do

```
export default class BaseForm extends ErrorComponent {
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.setState({
                reason: null
            });
```

it yells at me and says I shouldn't use `setState` in the constructor.

And if I do

```
export default class BaseForm extends ErrorComponent {
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                reason: null
            };
```

It seems to be overwriting the state from the `ErrorComponent` constructor. How do I set the state without overriding the state from the class I'm extending from?

Comment: @keikai are you saying it's impossible to inherit the state from the class I'm extending?

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default class BaseForm extends ErrorComponent {
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = Object.assign(this.state, {
                reason: null,
            });
```

Comment: And I do have `"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",` in my dependencies as [this](http://www.dalecudmore.com/react-three-dots-error) seems to recommend

Answer (score 2):

You should not use inheritance in React until or unless if the required functionality cannot be achieved with composition. it's `React` Anti Pattern.

React has a powerful composition model, and is recommend to use composition instead of inheritance to reuse code between components.

> Props and composition give you all the flexibility you need to customize a component’s look and behavior in an explicit and safe way. Remember that components may accept arbitrary props, including primitive values, React elements, or functions.

You should use it like below.

**ErrorComponent**

```
export default class ErrorComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState({...this.props.childState });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And then wrap the `BaseForm` with `ErrorComponent`.

```
export default class BaseForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState({
      reason: null
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ErrorComponent childState={this.state}>
        <div>
          some thing
      </div>
      </ErrorComponent>

    )
  }
}
```

You could read more about [Composition vs Inheritance in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)